# Extract value between date and last td

Tags: regex

I have the following piece of HTML from which I want to extract the last value:

```
>2 Jan 2015</td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">104.24</td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">104.72</td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">102.52</td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">103.60</td>
```

How can I do this using regex? Thanks

Comment: Could you give an example of what your want the output to be? I find your instructions a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for `103.60`, you can use this regex:

```
.*<td.*?>(.*?)</td>
```

`.*<td.*?` - this will look for everything before the `>` element in the last `<td.*`.

`>` - this causes the `?` to stop

`(.*?)` - this captures all the content before the `</td>`

`</td`> - this cause the `?` to stop

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I just extended it a bit more to include the date